# What other action than commit counts to last update date?

Tags: github

After I've searched and found one up-to-date plugin:
[image]

I've went to its page and it appeared last update info was misleading, because the project is actually not maintaned any more - latest commit is not 2 days old, but 2 years old:

[image]

Now I'm curious, what action could possibly change the displayed "last update" date which appears in GitHub's search view?

Are there any other alternatives to GitHub Search combined with "Recently updated" sorting which would list **genuinely updated** projects first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Updated" takes into account issues and pull requests I believe, and you can see a pull request was updated 2 days ago for the repository in your screenshot

[image: screenshot of pull request updated notifier]

I'm not sure if you can sort by pushed date, but you can add it as a [search argument](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/#search-based-on-when-a-repository-was-created-or-last-updated) with a date range to get only repositories with commits after a certain date.